# How to explicitly specify EOF in Yacc (Linux Bison)?

Tags: bison, yacc

I built an SQL parser using lex (flex) and yacc (bison) on Linux, and this parser must parse SQL with '; ' ends, it parses SQL correctly like this:
`select * from table_a;`

But when I type the following incorrect SQL, it still works:
`select * from table_a; where`

I wonder if the yacc rule supports marking an EOF at the end of the input, so that the error can be reported in time if the error syntax is encountered.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you can avoid this end-of-stream issue by wrapping your top-level rule as a X' -> X EOF, where EOF is a token you define in the parser and yield using the <<EOF>> rule in flex.